# Should threads act on separate memory?

Tags: c++, multithreading, shared-memory

I have a C++ program whose task is to analyse a stream of binary data (typically it's a file on disk) and extract some information. This task is "memory-less", meaning that the outcome of each step is independent of the previous one. Because of this, I thought to speed it up by giving the data to separate threads in order to improve performance.

For now, the data is read in blocks of 1GB at a time and saved in an array to avoid I/O bottlenecks. Should I separate the data in `n` chunks/arrays (where `n` is the number of threads) or is a single array accessed by multiple threads not an issue?

I have a C++ program whose task is to analyse a stream of binary data (typically it's a file on disk) and extract some information. This task is "memory-less", meaning that the outcome of each step is independent of the previous one. Because of this, I thought to speed it up by giving the data to separate threads in order to improve performance.

For now, the data is read in blocks of 1GB at a time and saved in an array to avoid I/O bottlenecks. Should I separate the data in `n` chunks/arrays (where `n` is the number of threads) or is a single array accessed by multiple threads not an issue?

**EDIT 1: data and anlaysis specification**
I realize that the wording of the problem might be too broad, as pointed out by one of the comments. I will try to go into a bit more detail.

The data being analysed is a series of unsigned 64bits integers generated by a so-called "time-to-digital" converter (TDC), storing a timestamp information about some event they register. My TDC has multiple channels, so each timestamp has information about which channel triggered (first 3 bits), whether that was a rising or falling edge trigger (4th bit), and the actual time (in clock ticks since powering up the TDC, last 60 bits).

The timestamps, of course, are saved in the file chronologically. The task is finding coincidence events between channels within a certain time window which the user sets. So you keep reading the timestamps and when you find two in the channels of interest whose distance in time is less than the set one, you increase the number of coincidence events.

These files can be quite big (tens of GB) and the number of timestamps enormous (one clock tick is 80 **pico**seconds).

For now I only go through the whole file once, and the idea was to "cut it" in smaller pieces that would then be analysed by different threads. The possible loss of events between the cuts is acceptable for me, since, at most will be 2 over hundreds of thousands.

Of course, they would **only read** data from the file/memory. I can write the coincidence counts in three separate variables and then sum them when all threads finish, if this helps avoiding sync problems.

I hope now things are clearer.

Comment: There are four kinds of [storage durations](https://en.cppreference.com/book/storage_durations) in C++.  Thread local being one of them. As-is the topic is too broad for SO format. Possibly unclear too.

Comment: Maybe you meant stateless instead of memory-less?

Comment: Threads won't help if your processing is CPU bound, but you can use processes instead if it is.

Comment: you can read a block of memory from any number of threads you like, as long as none of them is changing it (meaning the part that could be accessed by other threads)

Comment: 1GB??  Seriously?

Comment: If they are not going to modify the data then it would be fine for all of them to access the single array without any sync.

Comment: It is not the best strategy, execution time will be set by the slowest thread.  Can be very slow on a hyper-threaded core.  Breaking it in smaller units with a thread consuming another unit when it is done processing one does not have that problem.

Comment: Thanks for the comments! I have updated the question with (a lot) more info about what type of data and data analysis is being done.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, the same array can be accessed by multiple threads: if threads only read the array (which seems to be the case here), you won't have false sharing effects.

And to optimize cache use, you could make each thread read consecutive elements of the array (i.e **not** interleave reads between threads).

As a side-note, you may want to reconsider the 1GB block : that's a lot! Have you measured that it's better than, say, 1MB or 10KB ?

You also might want to parallelize "file reading" (one small chunk at a time) and "processing the content that was read" (using many threads as you do), using (at least) 2 arrays (one is being processed, the other will receive the next read)

Comment: I believe it would also help to have each chunk cache aligned, no?

Comment: @Tudor yes, but if we're talking 1GB blocks it won't make a big difference :)

Comment: Side note: even writing to the array is not an issue if each thread only writes to its "own" section it reads from...

Comment: @Aconcagua agreed, if by section you mean L1 cache-aligned sections, to avoid false sharing. I didn't want to go in the details here, since the question was about just reading.

Comment: For me, the way you worded it makes it sound like two consecutive elements should be given to two consecutive threads. But I suspect it is supposed to mean that each thread should be given a contiguous block

Comment: @Galik Thanks, I rephrased it, does it make more sense to you now?

Comment: I was (probably mistakenly) convinced that multiple readings from a file would be slower than a single read that saves the necessary (or most of the) data in memory. I noticed, for example, that reading a single timestamp (see edit) from the file is much much slower than "saving" a full chunk in memory an then processing that, but I have no timing data for different sizes of the block.

Comment: @mmassaro (deleted my earlier comment, I didn't understand what you were saying) if you parallelize `file reading` with `processing the content of the file` (using 2 buffers for example) then I think the time it takes will be the same (but you need to read at least 4kb of data for example). But it will use less memory, if you read the file one chunk at a time.

Comment: @Oliver Sohn thanks for the hint. That might be second improvement, but for now I'm more interested in speeding up the analysis. I'm the only user of this program for now, so I don't really care for now how much memory I use. :)

Comment: @mmassaro Sure, don't spend time on unessential stuff. Note that using small chunks of memory could also speed up the analysis, because of caching.